# encryption program from py to exe

Tags: python, python-2.7, encryption, exe, pyinstaller

I made a encryption program that encrypts files of your chose with a password and can only be unlocked with that certan password.

When I run this file in .py form it has no problems, but when I convert it into a .exe file with pyinstaller, It doesnt work anymore

I use the command

```
pyinstaller -F en-decryptor-v2.py
```

But when I run this file I get this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "en-decryptor-v2.py", line 2, in <module>
    from Crypto.Cipher import AES
  File "c:\python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
 line 396, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "c:\python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
 line 396, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\_mode_ecb.py", line 46, in <module>
  File "site-packages\Crypto\Util\_raw_api.py", line 258, in load_pycryptodome_r
aw_lib
OSError: Cannot load native module 'Crypto.Cipher._raw_ecb': Trying '_raw_ecb.py
d': Failed to load dynlib/dll 'C:\\Users\\STEFA_~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI81
~1\\Crypto\\Util\\..\\Cipher\\_raw_ecb.pyd'. Most probably this dynlib/dll was n
ot found when the application was frozen.
[3960] Failed to execute script en-decryptor-v2
```

Comment: Did you find [this](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2881)?